# Deleting Multiple Records using Checkboxes in PHP

Tags: php

I am having an issue where I need to be able to delete multiple records using checkboxes.

Here is the code that I currently have.

```
<?php 
$host       = "localhost";
$user       = "root";
$pass       = "";
$dbName     = "ticket_history";
$table_name = "ticket_history";

################ Connect to the Database and SELECT DATA ####################################
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect");
mysql_select_db($dbName);
$query = "SELECT Date,Ticket_Number,Description,Result FROM $table_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
#############################################################################################
?>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE></TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
<table width=50%>
    <form method="post" action="insert_ticket.php">
        <table width border='0'>
            <tr><td> &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Date:<input type="text" name="date"/></td>
            <td>Ticket #:<input type="text" name="ticket"/></td></tr>
            <table>
                <tr><td>Description:<TEXTAREA COLS=50 name="description"></TEXTAREA></td></tr>
                <tr><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Result     :<TEXTAREA COLS=50 name="result"></TEXTAREA></td></tr>
            <tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add"/></td></tr>
            </table>
        </table>
    </form>
    <form method="post" action="delete_ticket.php">
    <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/>
    </form>
</table>

<?php
print "<table width=80% border=1>\n"; 
$cols = 0; 
while ($get_info = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){ 
$id = $get_info->id;
if($cols == 0) 
{ 
  $cols = 1; 
  print "<tr>";
  print "<th>Select</th>";  
  foreach($get_info as $col => $value) 
  { 

    print "<th>$col</th>"; 
  } 
  print "<tr>\n"; 
} 
print "<tr>\n"; 
print "<td><input type='checkbox' name='selected[]' id='checkbox[]' value=$id></td>";
foreach ($get_info as $field) 
print "\t<td align='center'><font face=arial size=1/>$field</font></td>\n"; 
print "</tr>\n"; 
} 
print "</table>\n"; 
mysql_close();
?>

<!------------------------------------------------------------!>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Delete.php
<?php
$host       = "localhost";
$user       = "root";
$pass       = "";
$dbName     = "ticket_history";
$table_name = "ticket_history";

################ Connect to the Database and SELECT DATA ####################################
$conn = mysql_connect($host, $user, $pass) or die ("Unable to connect");
mysql_select_db($dbName);
$query = "SELECT Date,Ticket_Number,Description,Result FROM $table_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);
#####################################


if($_POST['delete']) {
    $checkbox = $_POST['selected'];
    $countCheck = count($_POST['selected']);

    for($i=0;$i<$countCheck;$i++) {
        $del_id = $checkbox[$i];

    $sql = "DELETE FROM ticket_history WHERE Auto = $del_id";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    }
}
?>
```

I just want to be able to delete rows checked.  How would I go about doing this effectively and efficiently?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: something like `DELETE FROM tablename WHERE Auto IN ('.implode(',',array_map('intval',$_POST['selected'])).')'`

Comment: You should be cautious with this method of directly using the $_POST values. The query you posted is susceptible to XSS attacks. Wrikken has the gist of it though, you'll want to use implode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer to your question would be to use:

```
$sql = sprintf('DELETE FROM ticket_history WHERE Auto IN ()', 
    implode(',', $checkbox));
```

However as people will jump in and tell you, you are vulnerable to SQL injection. You should never trust user input. You are deleting using an ID, which I'm assuming must be an integer.

Using something like this will validate that:

```
$ids = array();
foreach($_POST['selected'] as $selected) {
    if (ctype_digit($selected)) {
        $ids[] = $selected;
    }
    else {
        // If one is invalid, I would assume nothing can be trusted
        // Depends how you want to handle the error.
        die('Invalid input');
    }
}

$sql = sprintf('DELETE FROM ticket_history WHERE Auto IN (%s)', 
    implode(',', $ids));
```

---

**Other issues:**

You seem to be using id's, but have not selected that field in your initial query.

```
$query = "SELECT Date,Ticket_Number,Description,Result FROM $table_name";
```

Then you reference:

```
$id = $get_info->id;
```

Check the HTML output is actually what you expect.

In your delete query, you are referencing the field Auto. Is that your ID field?

And lastly, there no checking if the user has permission to do so.  If this is a public site anyone can delete from that table.

---

Example of using two submit buttons within one form:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['create'])) {
    echo "Create!";
}
elseif (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    echo "Delete!";
}
?>
<html>
    <form method="post">
        <input type="submit" name="create" value="Create"/>
        <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete"/>
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: @Jacob - Yes Auto is the ID field.  Also, this is not a public site, but a personal.

Comment: @jmg0880, then you need to select the Auto field in your query, and reference it as such. `$id = $get_info->Auto`.

Comment: @Jacob,  I am still having trouble with this.  How I just don't get how to get this.

Comment: @jmg0880 what trouble are you having?

Comment: @Jacob, It is telling me that Undefined index: selected in C:\wamp\www\ticket_history\delete_ticket.php on line 17.  It is saying that "SELECTED" is undefined, which is in the code you have suggested.

Comment: @jmg0880 Oh... your checkboxes aren't within your delete_ticket form. They need to be inside the <form> tags.

Comment: @Jacob, hmm seems like it will not delete even after using the delete statement in your code above :(

Comment: @jmg0880 because the checkbox values are not being sent, because they are not within the <form> tags.

Comment: @Jacob,Would there be an easy way to incorporate all of that into the form?

Comment: @Jacob: You're missing a `%s` in your sprintf() call. As it stands now, you could just "print()" for the exact same effect.

Comment: @Jacob - ok this is what the output is:  It looks like it is executing the statement but not deleting 

DELETE FROM ticket_history WHERE Auto IN ()DELETE FROM ticket_history WHERE Auto IN ()DELETE FROM ticket_history WHERE Auto IN ()DELETE FROM ticket_history WHERE Auto IN ()Fail

Comment: @jmg0880 you can use one form, and check the POST for the name/value pair for the submit button that was pressed. I'd recommend playing with different scenarios and using `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's getting sent.

Comment: @Jacob, that works now!!! but do you think you could explain to me the sprintf function?  and what %s is for?  Or could you point me to a resource so that I could grasp the concepts a little better :)

Comment: @Jacob, do you think you could give me an example of using 1 form for multiple submit buttons?

Comment: @jmg0880 added form example to my answer, and see [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php). %s means to insert the argument as a string.

Comment: @Jacob, how do i UNSET the value after it has been clicked and the info has been added ?

Comment: @jmg0880 I don't understand what you mean or why you would want to.

Comment: @Jacob, it seems when I hit ADD it doesnt display the add until i hit ADD twice.  Then the when i hit DELETE, it doesnt delete on the first try and even ADDS rows.